# How do I set the developer display name in Google's Chrome Web Store when an extension is associated with a verfied site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

At https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard, there is a section titled "Your Developer Account" with a line that says "Edit your developer display name" as a hyperlink, and then shows the current value of the developer display name in bold.  That is supposed to set the value of what follows "offered by" on the developer's add-on page.

If the extension is associated with a verified website, even if the domain name is complex like sub.myhost.tld/some/verified/path, what follows "offered by" is that path.  For example, [the eBay add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ebay/bnadbgmffcofipfljniafanjcafjlbom) is "offered by anywhere.ebay.com." Associating an extension with a verified site is necessary for features like permitting [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) from that site.

[Aditya Bhaskar](http://c306.net/converge/2015/showing-developer-name-in-chrome-web-store/) points out the lack of documentation and concludes that it's not possible to both set the developer name AND support inline installation etc., but is he right?  Or is there actually a way to set the developer display name while retaining the functional benefits of verified site association?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no official docs regarding to this issue. How about you verify the official site and edit your developer display name at the same time?

Comment: Have you found a timing of that that works?  As long as there's a verified site associate with the extension, any edits to the developer display name seem to be irrelevant to what's displayed.

Comment: As far as I know, the feature you're wondering is not accessible currently. So I'd say you could try, but it seems nothing in it.